# Hash function in an unordered_set

Tags: c++, hashtable, unordered-set

I am using an unordered_set to implement a hash table. I can't figure out how to use the find function. I keep getting a seg fault when I run this code. I know its because find() is not finding an element but it should. My question is how do I properly use the find with the custom hash function I have provided?

```
unordered_set<Play*, Play::Hash> hashedData
unordered_set<Play*>::iterator got;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  got = hashedData.find(data[i]);

  cout << (*got)->getSummary() << endl << endl;
}
```

data is just a

```
vector<Play*>
```

and my hash function looks like this

```
struct Hash {
    size_t operator()(Play* const &x) const {
      size_t t = 0;
      static int hash = 0;

      string u = x->getOffense();
      string v = x->getDefence();
      string w = x->getPlayDesc();

      t = u.length() + v.length() + w.length();
      t += hash;
      ++hash;

      return t;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know the root cause why you can't find the element which it should.

**Do you use staic variale in you `Hash` function.**

Change you `Hash` function to like this:

```
struct Hash
{
    size_t operator()(Play* const &x) const 
    {
        size_t t = 0;
        string u = x->getOffense();
        string v = x->getDefence();
        string w = x->getPlayDesc();

        t = u.length() + v.length() + w.length();
        return t;
    }
};
```

This function has problem, when the same object `A` call this function twice, the result is different. Because you use a static variable `static int hash = 0;`. So in your case when you construct the `hashedData`, the function `Hash` call once, when you use `find` function, the same object call `Hash` again, but you got different result, so the funtiocn `find` return `hashedData.end()`.

when you call `cout << (*got)->getSummary() << endl << endl;`, you will meet a seg fault.
you should do like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) 
{
    got = hashedData.find(data[i]);
    if (got != hashedData.end())
    {
        cout<<(*got)->getSummary()<<endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your own Pred evaluator as the third argument to your unordered_set.  You can then inspect the two arguments being compared. Also verify your iterator does not equal end() after the call to find.